# Does the Favor of the Pope begin in play in Condottiere?

Tags: condottiere

In [Condottiere](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/112/condottiere), does the Favor of the Pope (white token) begin in play or does it not come into play until the first Bishop card is played?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It begins off of the board.** The initial setup is illustrated on p. 4 of the [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Condottiere/Condottiere_Rules_English.pdf). It is also worth mentioning that when a player plays a Bishop card, that player can choose to remove the Favor of the Pope token from the board (or leave it off) rather than place it in any region.